# Android Logic needs work

Tags: android, database, android-emulator, logic

I am try to make a application in which i create a list view with two textview and one check box field and i want when i click on check box to check then both textview values are add to database and when i click on same check box to uncheck a check box then both previously add values deleted from database.

i am able to code to add data values on database on check event but not able to delete these values on uncheck the check box.

```
package data.base;

import com.example.phone_no.DBhelper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Second extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
 String string1[];

 Context context;
    String string[];
     TextView textView;
    TextView textView1,textView2;

    CheckBox checkBox;
    EditText editText;
    String string2[];

    public Second(Context context, String[] objects, String[] Object1,String[] object2)
    {

        super(context,R.layout.main,R.id.text1, objects);
        System.out.println("you in under super");
        this.context=context;
        this.string=objects;
        this.string1=Object1;
        this.string2 = object2;
      //  this.imageView = Object3;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        System.out.println("you in under getview");
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,parent,false);
          textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        System.out.println("you in under inflator");

        textView1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
       // imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.text3);
        textView.setText(string[position]);
        textView1.setText(string1[position]);
        System.out.println("you are above of return");
        checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        textView2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text3);
        textView2.setText(string2[position]);



        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if(checkBox.isChecked())   
               {

                 System.out.println("under check");
                 DBhelper DB = new DBhelper(context);
                 DB.open();
                 DB.delete_image(string2[position]);
                 DB.close();

               }

                else

               {
                   System.out.println("underhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh check");
                DBhelper DB = new DBhelper(context);
                DB.open();
                DB.adddata(string2[position], string[position], string1[position]);
                DB.getAlldata();
                DB.close();

               }



            }
        });












        return view;    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.

    }

}
```

This is my DBhelper class which maintain database actions:

```
package com.example.phone_no;



import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBhelper {
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "names";

public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phoneno";

private final Context ourContext;
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Contactinfo";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 27;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactdata.db";
private DbHelper ourHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
// end for location
private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        /*db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NULL , "
                + KEY_PHONE + " INTEGER NULL);");*/
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER , " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NULL , "
                + KEY_PHONE + " INTEGER NULL);");

        // string value
        String y = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  , " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NULL , "
                + KEY_PHONE + " INTEGER NULL);";

        System.out.println("query" + y);
        Log.d("query", y);






    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}

public DBhelper(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
}
public DBhelper open() throws SQLException 
{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() 
{
    ourHelper.close();
}
public long adddata(String id,String name,String number) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // add the custom Image Gallery Image Path to Data Base
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_ID, id);
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_PHONE, number);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public void getAlldata() 
{
    Cursor details = null;
    if (ourDatabase.isOpen() == false)

        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    if (ourDatabase.isOpen()) 
    {
        details = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
         for(details.moveToFirst();!details.isAfterLast();details.moveToNext())
        {
             String a=details.getString(0);
            String b=details.getString(1);
            String c=details.getString(2);
            System.out.println("id--"+a+"name"+b+"phoneno"+c);
        }



    }


}
public long delete_image(String id) 
  {
    if (ourDatabase.isOpen() == false)
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      if (ourDatabase.isOpen()) 
        {
            return ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null);
        }
        return 0;
    }



}
```

This is my second Class file name Second.java In which i cant create a logic in under if condition.

```
package data.base;

import com.example.phone_no.DBhelper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Second extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
 String string1[];

 Context context;
    String string[];
     TextView textView;
    TextView textView1,textView2;

    CheckBox checkBox;
    EditText editText;
    String string2[];

    public Second(Context context, String[] objects, String[] Object1,String[] object2)
    {

        super(context,R.layout.main,R.id.text1, objects);
        System.out.println("you in under super");
        this.context=context;
        this.string=objects;
        this.string1=Object1;
        this.string2 = object2;
      //  this.imageView = Object3;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        System.out.println("you in under getview");
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,parent,false);
          textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        System.out.println("you in under inflator");

        textView1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
       // imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.text3);
        textView.setText(string[position]);
        textView1.setText(string1[position]);
        System.out.println("you are above of return");
        checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        textView2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text3);
        textView2.setText(string2[position]);



        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if(checkBox.isChecked())   
               {

                 System.out.println("under check");
                 DBhelper DB = new DBhelper(context);
                 DB.open();
                 DB.delete_image(string2[position]);
                 DB.close();

               }

                else

               {
                   System.out.println("underhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh check");
                DBhelper DB = new DBhelper(context);
                DB.open();
                DB.adddata(string2[position], string[position], string1[position]);
                DB.getAlldata();
                DB.close();

               }



            }
        });












        return view;    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.

    }


}
```

In if condition it not goes to under first section in which i used delete method that's why it always add record in data base on check and uncheck event of check box.

please help. thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try edit this

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            if(!arg1)   
           {

             System.out.println("under check");
             DBhelper DB = new DBhelper(context);
             DB.open();
             DB.delete_image(string2[position]);
             DB.close();

           }

            else

           {
               System.out.println("underhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh check");
            DBhelper DB = new DBhelper(context);
            DB.open();
            DB.adddata(string2[position], string[position], string1[position]);
            DB.getAlldata();
            DB.close();

           }

        }
    });
```

And edit this

```
public boolean delete_image(int id) 

{
    if (ourDatabase.isOpen() == false)
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      if (ourDatabase.isOpen()) 
        {
            return ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this helped you.

Comment: My problem is here that my code is deleted the records on the basis of Record id Which is come in string2[position] , then when i run code first time then check box is already unchecked and according to your code when check box is unchecked then it delete record .......but record is not present in database bcoz it created on the check event .....so emulator gives a error that you dont have a record which id is A which is first fatch in string2[position] ......thats my problem

Comment: In `delete_image()` edit return to this `return ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;`.

Comment: You pass `id` as String for that you should convert it to Integer because you created `id` integer in table.